# How to install Java on a Mac

Tags: java, macos

[image: this is the current image in terminal]

I have been doing some research on how to install Java jre and jdk on correct PATH. I lack the comprehension when coming to understand what others would instruct on to change path in the terminal. even after several trial. I would still get an error.

How can I properly install Java and have it run so I can run my Java IDE.

Comment: Did you try just downloading the jdk dmg file and installing it? https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Comment: There isn't much to research, so: how did you install it? (did you download it, if so where and how did you then process with that download; did you use homebrew; did you do something else...?)

Comment: I am trying to install eclipse. I do have jre install and jdk.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I should have been more specific. I have no problem with windows, its just os x i have trouble with. I have macbook os x maverick, macbook late 2008, I can't get the el capitan os. I installed like any other programs. it never asked where to installed on to my macbook.

Comment: Can you check the output from `ls -l /usr/bin/java`. Since java_home works, I wonder if your 'java' simlink is pointed at the wrong thing or doesn't exist. Both can give you a command not found.

Comment: @matt this eclipse can't find the java I installed or it say it need jre or jdk. I did what you say and the ls -l /usr/bin/Java - "no such file or directory

Comment: thank you for help the issue got solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have been doing some research on how to install Java jre and jdk on
>   correct PATH.

JRE has been discontinued since Java 11. Since you are talking about Java 14, there is no JRE for it. You just need to install (and configure, if required) JDK.

Use the following command and then check `java -version`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Note that it will work only for your current session i.e. `java -version` won't work in another terminal window.

To set `JAVA_HOME` permanently, do as follows:

```
$ cd ~
$ vi .bash_profile
```

Write the following line into `.bash_profile` file, save and quit:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Then refresh (read and execute `.bash_profile`)

```
$ source .bash_profile
```

And finally test

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
$ java -version
```

**Note:** Also, [This thread](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk/issues/329) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

## In 2022, you can use just `brew`

```
brew install openjdk
```

and maybe you need to update `PATH` env:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"
```

### …and for the future give a try to [`sdkman`](https://sdkman.io/), is better than `brew`

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

then open a **new shell** and try `list` to see what you could install ;-)

```
sdk list java
```

At time of writing you could use:

```
sdk install java 17.0.1-tem
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to determine what java installations you currently have installed is by running:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

This will return the default Java jdk you currently have installed. You could also run:

```
java -v
```

Which will show you the current version of the first JDK that your path encounters.

If you would like to view all Java JDK versions that you have installed, you can run the first command mentioned with the `-V` (verbose) flag, and it will list the paths to all you have installed.

If you have multiple versions installed, you can amend your `$PATH` variable inside either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. (Note these are the files for my system, macOS, but the profile files may be different for Linux installations, I simply do not know). There is a convention you can read about regarding where you should do it.

Quite simply, if the version you do NOT want is the one that appears when you run `java -v` or `which java` then you must add the path to the desired JDK to your `$PATH` as mentioned.

In order to view your current path, you can run `echo $PATH`

In order to amend your path you will add a command similar to the following to one of the bash profile files for your system:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/[NEW_PATH]
```

or

```
export PATH=[DESIRED_PATH]:$PATH
```

The first command adds to the end of your path, the second adds to the beginning.

Most likely you may want to add the path to your desired JDK in the beginning of your existing `$PATH` variable.

Obviously, be very careful with changing your path, you don't want other programs to break, so make sure you simply add the desired JDK path in front of your original variable, so that the only related program, java, has a change.

Comment: This is a big post for not having a clue what the user tried. I'll be impressed if it helps.

Comment: I had the time, if they have more specifics they can always ask or input. Maybe it'll help someone other than the poster.

Comment: the issue is when i check for java -version, I got command not found. the only java I have installed is the jdk 14.01 and the recent java jre 8.251

Comment: Please make sure you are running either `java -v` or `java --version` . If you use a whole word flag with a single dash it will not work.

Comment: @antong either one provided me with a version. it say "command not found"

Comment: thank you for the help but someone were dumb it down for me to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

## Installer updates paths automatically

I have always found that after using an installer to install a Java implementation on macOS, the correct paths are already set for me. No additional configuration needed.

After the installer is done, in a terminal app run:

```bash
java --version
```

…to verify your newly installed Java implementation.

## IDE uses its own JVM

You said:

> have it run so I can run my Java IDE.

Be aware that some [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s such as [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) come bundled with their own Java implementation. So your downloaded [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) would *not* actually be running your IDE. This internal JVM is used to run the IDE itself.

This JVM could be used to run your app in development, as I recall. But you likely will want to download and install a JVM of a version (and possibly vendor) akin to what will be used in production.

Within your IDE settings, project settings, and build-tool settings (Maven, Gradle, etc.), you can tell the IDE what external JVM to use to run your app. Meanwhile the IDE continues to run itself using its own internally-bundled JVM.

---

Here is a flowchart I made to help explain the various implementations. All but the last two of these vendors likely provide an installer app for your Mac.

If you have no reason to choose a particular vendor, I suggest using [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net), a cooperative effort supported by many in the Java community including most (if not all) of these vendors listed here.

For more info, read the important posting: [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244).

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]